# Aws MWAA Airflow rest api

Tags: airflow, mwaa

Iam trying to hit the api provided in the airflow ui on aws console. I tried to access the web server but when i try to get the list of dags iam getting unauthorized error. Do we need any role or permission to access rest api and get the expected response out. I tried with webtoken creation and passed in to hit api. Tried with basic auth and aws signatures as well.

Do we need any extra permissions?

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the Airflow API, an IAM entity (e.g. user, role, etc) needs access to one or more of the following managed permissions policies:

1. `AmazonMWAAFullConsoleAccess`
2. `AmazonMWAAFullApiAccess`
3. `AmazonMWAAReadOnlyAccess`
4. `AmazonMWAAWebServerAccess`
5. `AmazonMWAAAirflowCliAccess`

References:

1. [Accessing an Amazon MWAA environment (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/access-policies.html#full-access-policy)
2. [Creating an Apache Airflow web login token (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/call-mwaa-apis-web.html#access-airflow-ui-prereqs-access)